# Convert const function code from JSX to TSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to convert the way an alternate route component is defined in JSX an equivalent TypeScript TSX file. (1)

The JSX syntax is like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
        localStorage.getItem('user')
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
    )} />
)
```

I've tried to convert it to TypeScript, but in Visual Studio, the `<Component` part (see below) is underlined and the TypeScript compiler tells me

```
(TS) JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.
```

I don't really understand the `({ component: Component, ...rest })` syntax of the lambda function. This is as far as I've gotten on writing it in TypeScript.

```
export function PrivateRoute(Component: React.Component, ...rest: any[]) {
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            localStorage.getItem('user')
                ? <Component {...props} />
                : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
        )} />
    );
};
```

Any suggestions?

References:

1. https://www.pointblankdevelopment.com.au/blog/135/react-redux-with-aspnet-core-20-login-registration-tutorial-example#private-route-jsx

Comment: `({ component: Component, ...rest })` means taking a `component` attribute from the object via destructuring and renaming it to `Component` in the function scope, and putting the rest of the attributes of the object in a variable named `rest` through the "rest" operator (the `...`). I hope that clears it up, I don't know TS so I can't help you refactor that :)

Comment: OK that's interesting. Does that syntax have a name I can google or is there any documentation you can point to on it?

Comment: The good old MDN documentation has a lot of examples. Note that destructuring and rest/spread operators are available on arrays and objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: why dont you use the class syntax

Comment: How would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error - JSX/TSX `<Component ...` will be converted to something like `React.createElement(Component...`, so `Component` type should be a function/class, **not** an instance. Hence the proper typing for it will be `ComponentType`.

Regarding `{ component: Component, ...rest }` - this is an [object destructuring with assignment to new variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names). Passed parameter is unpacked to variables `Component` and `rest` (`component` property of the parameter goes to `Component` variable and all the rest properties go to `rest` variable)

To sum up, the resulting typing might look like:

```
type RouteProps = { component: React.ComponentType };
export function PrivateRoute(
    { component: Component, ...rest }: RouteProps) {
    ...
};
```

Comment: The TypeScript compiler seems to want a type argument for `React.ComponentType`. Any hints on what that should be?

Comment: `ComponentType<P={}>` [has default type parameter](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L48) so it shouldn't be required. Anyway this is Prop types of component. If it doesn't work for you without explicitly specifying the type argument you can make `PrivateRoute<T>` generic or just use `React.ComponentType<any>`, but this is definitely not required as we see in typings